# Docker Running Apache Ignite Official Images memory continues to increase

Tags: docker, ignite

- docker pull

I pull the image provided by Apache ignite, address: https://hub.docker.com/r/apacheignite/ignite.
Pull command: `docker pull apachesignite / signite.`

- docker run

Then execute the dock run command: `docker run - ITD -- CPU set CPU s = - 0 "- M 4096m -- memory reservation 4096m -- name apachesignite_ ignite --net=host apacheignite/ ignite:2.10.0` .

- result

But after running for 2 days, we found that the memory used by it has been increasing, as shown in the figure:
[image]

Excuse me, this memory has been growing how to solve the situation?

Comment: This reads to me as: You're reserving 4G of memory and are worried that the application doesn't attempt to free up any memory when less than 500M are used. Check if you're observing a memory leak (most likely in custom code) or if garbage collection sets in when necessary (you can force it earlier by providing less memory, or use the instance more if that triggers memory allocation). What memory are you showing here anyway? Heap? Ignite's off-heap-data?

Comment: Hello, I just ran this image and did not modify any of its configuration. I suspect that the 2.10 version image has a memory leak problem.

Comment: I try to allocate the memory to 400MB. As a result, docker ended automatically after running for less than 20 minutes, and it seems that no garbage collection was performed. The Linux system log shows an error message: Apr 21 17:42:17 photon-PVNS-126 kernel: Memory cgroup out of memory: Kill process 27289 (java) score 1011 or sacrifice child
Apr 21 17:42:17 photon-PVNS-126 kernel: Killed process 27289 (java) total-vm:2639928kB, anon-rss:399312kB, file-rss:13764kB, shmem-rss:0kB

Comment: memory leaks in a garbage collected system look like a sawtooth (with a slightly upward tilt), not like a straight line. And if 400M are not enough to run at all, that also proves nothing

Comment: It is indeed not a continuous jagged image, but the memory occupied is slowly increasing. This is a problem. I am not sure if it is a configuration problem or Apache Ignite has this problem. Is there any way to test or troubleshoot whose problem is?

Comment: It's not that simple. 400M _to docker_? When it runs a jvm that is configured for 1G (making up numbers here) it will rather die than garbage collect.